# Does .comm create a local or global variable?

Tags: assembly, powerpc

```
__asm void DISABLE_INT( void )
{
    .comm DISABLE_VAR,4,4
    mfmsr   r3          ; Get current MSR
    rlwinm  r4,r3,0,17,15       ; Mask External Interrupt Enable bit
    mtmsr   r4          ;  in MSR (bit 16)
    sync                ; Must sync because of chip bug in some 603E.
    addis   r4,r0,DISABLE_VAR@ha
    stw r3,DISABLE_VAR@l(r4)    
}
```

Does the `.comm` statement in the `__asm` block create a local or global variable?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your assembler. Assuming GNU `as` [the manual says](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Comm.html) global. You can use `.lcomm` for local.